# Replace single line with multiline code and vice versa

Tags: shell, sed

I want to replace a single line, `string1`, with a snippet of code. 
I could do it with a sed  command:

```
sed -i "s|..|a very long code|g"
```

The code could cover three rows. However, our code style requires the code must be under certain columns in each row. For formatting, I used "Enter" key press. It seems "Enter" keypress would lead to "unterminated s command" error.

Is there any good bash command to do it?

Also, how to replace this multiline code with a single line? The code has some `%`, `*` and some regex characters. Seems pattern space should not have them.

Comment: the real issue is I wanna to make  "multiline sed expression" work. like to include line continunation in sed expression . When I use "\" for line continunation. It has  unterminated `s' command error .Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\n` to indicate linebreaks.

```
:~> sed "s|string1|#include \"test.h\"\n#include \"release.h\"|g"
```

Would print

```c
#include "test.h"
#include "release.h"
```

You could enter spaces as required

```
:~> echo sleep100 | sed "s|sleep100|\
for (int i=0; i< 100; i++){\n\
sleep(1);\n}|g"
```

Would print a formatted loop construct

```
for (int i=0; i< 100; i++){
   sleep(1);
}
```

With a bit of roundabout coding you could even keep the necessary amount of whitespace in the beginning of each line of the sed command.

```
:~> bs4="$(printf '%b' '\b' '\b' '\b' '\b')" ;\
    echo sleep100 | sed "s|sleep100|\
    ${bs4}for (int i=0; i< 100; i++){\n\
    sleep(1);\n}|g"
```

The essence of the trick is to get over the limitation of `sed` that interprets `\b` escape differently. Instead of using the escape sequence we plant actual backspace characters to gobble up the extra spaces.

**P.S.** You could have special characters such as `$`, `%` and `*` in the replacement expression as soon as you escape them with backslashes as 
`\$`, `\%` and `\*` respectively.

Comment: yeah, I know . My point is not about '\n' .Issue is that  my code is too long to take up  3,4 lines. And the format is ugly.  my sed command would be in under if clause. so there is an indentation before "sed". However remaining 2 or 3 lines would start from the very beginning of the line.which is very horrible style. My real question is  how to format sed command

Comment: @user3529352 Just escape newlines with backslashes. See how I have edited the last example.

Comment: sed -i "s|string1|\
line1\n\
line2\n\
line3|g" afg .  This does not work.  error : sed: -e expression #1 .. unterminated `s' command

Comment: @user3529352 make sure you do not have any spaces left after `\\` at the end of line

Comment: Thank very much. It worked. I have another question for you last example.For backspace characters.    what is '%b'  in  printf ? I also want to include backspace in replacement string. As you said , pure '\b' not work, and hex value of backpspace '\x08' output  ^H ....

Comment: @user3529352 `%b` format in `printf` expands escaped sequences in the argument

Comment: Hi, I tried it. It also just displayed ^H, not  actual deletion of anyting.  bs="$(printf '%b' '\b' )"; sed -i "s|string1|string2${bs}string3|g file"

Comment: @user3529352 good point. `\b` only makes sense on a terminal that supports it. I.e. if you `cat`  the output to stdout, it will work. If you open it in an editor, `\b` would be displayed as `^H`

Comment: Opps. so what should I do now? because of pretty sed expression, I used "tab" keypress. However for pretty code format in final file, I need to delete that "tab". So I was thinking to include special characters in the replacement string

Comment: Anyway, Thank you very much.  I don't need to do this kind of change according to product desgin.